# Live Visual Tree Without StartupUri

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to explicitly enable **Live Visual Tree** for a WPF application?

I have a solution with few WPF applications. All except one enable the **Live Visual Tree** feature while debugging. After sometime trying to see what differs between the applications with Live Visual Tree working and the one where it doesn't, I found the source: **StartupUri** in **App.xaml**:

```xml
    <Application x:Class="some.app.long.name"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
       <Application.Resources>

        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

With a Window set at **StartupUri** property, the Live Visual Tree works fine. But a startup Window is not an option for that application since there are configuration, login and diagnosis windows that can be activated by a behind code of **App.xaml**.

And then we come back to my question: any chance to explicitly activate the tree explorer? Or have it working for any window being shown?

PS: Starting the application by its executable and then attaching the Visual Studio debugger works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem. I have several apps that don't have a `StartupUri`, and they all have the Live Visual Tree available during debugging.

Comment: I agree with @Keithernet. If- just to test- you set the `StartupUri` for that project, does the Live Visual Tree start working? If not then the problem is probably something else.

Comment: Ok, let me try additional tests like not having the `StartupUri` and commenting some code of that App.xaml.cs

Comment: We need to render a windows so that the Live Visual Tree will show.  If you don't want the StartupUri property, you can show windows by behind code of App.xaml. Such As : Startup="Application_Startup  and show a window in this method.

Comment: @KeithStein @Keithernet You're right: not having a `StartUpUri` was not the problem. Some nonsense code (erase some folder) was triggering an OS error access. I can't say if that exception was the cause to not have the Live Visual Tree but I am able now to at least, workaround the problema. Thank you!

Comment: About the question? Is there any action that I should take since I found the problem (and it was not my initial assumption?

Comment: If you found your own answer, you can actually post your own solution as the answer below and accept your own post. I've done this a number of times with my own questions. This will stop the question from showing as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments have warned me that my assumption of **Live Visual Tree** not working if there is no value for `StartUpUri` was wrong. And indeed it was.

The real reason I'm not sure yet but I could find where it was happening (a clueless attempt to clean up temporary folders when starting the application). So, **even without a `StartUpUri` window, the Live Visual Tree works!**

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)